# Razor & nested loops

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am just started to learn Razor and have a question regarding nested loops.

It renders everything correctly using the following code

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
{
    foreach (var item in group.Items)
    {
        <span>@item.Title</item>
    }
}
```

but does not when I wrap the second foreach with "div" tags. It saying the item variable does not exist in that case.

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
{
    <div>
    foreach (var item in group.Items)
    {
        <span>@item.Title</item>
    }
    </div>
}
```

I made it work using the following code, but doubt it is the best solution

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
{
    @Html.Raw("<div>");
    foreach (var item in group.Items)
    {
        <span>@item.Title</item>
    }
    @Html.Raw("</div>");
}
```

Comment: I think that's because if you add markup you need to add the "@" symbol to the second foreach too.

Answer (score 5):

`@` means "hey, here's some code." If you drop back into markup, you need to remind razor that there's code coming. I believe what you want it is

```
@foreach (var group in Model.Groups)
{
    <div>
    @foreach (var item in group.Items)
    {
        <span>@item.Title</item>
    }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you. @ in front of the second foreach solved it

Comment: @user1050035 if your issue is fixed, why don't you mark this answer the Accepted Answer.